# how to append text into same file for each execution of a program

Tags: c#, trace

Below code is writing trace on a text file correctly, but for each program execution (multi-threaded and loop), a different file is generated.

how to make a single file output with all the content. Thanks!

```
private static void InitiateTracer()  
  {  
    Trace.Listeners.Clear();  
    var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;  
    var twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener("log.txt")  
    {  
      Name = "TextLogger",  
      TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.ThreadId | TraceOptions.DateTime  
    };  
    var ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false) { TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime };  
    Trace.Listeners.Add(twtl);  
    Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);  
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;  
  }
```

Comment: try `new TextWriterTraceListener(File.Open("log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))`

Comment: it's saying cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
TextWriterTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
```